# how to pass dictionary in tableview cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

    let element = ["Sports": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios"),"Grocery":#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios"),"Cosmetics":#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView1.delegate = self
        tableView1.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return element.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell",for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = element.keys

        cell.imageView?.image = element.values
        return cell
    }

}
```

hey guys how can i show dictionary key and value in same cell.

Comment: First of all `dictionary` doesn't use for `indexing` its a `key-value` pair. For `index` there is `Array`.

Answer (score 6):

> Add type to array as `[String: UIImage]` and typecast `element.keys` and `element.values` to Array as:
>
> **Array(element.keys)** and **Array(element.values)**

If you does not typecast `element.keys` and `element.values` to Array then you will receive error like `Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, UIImage>.Keys' with an index of type 'Int`

```
let element: [String: UIImage] = ["Sports": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios"),"Grocery":#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios"),"Cosmetics":#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios")]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell",for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = Array(element.keys)[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = Array(element.values)[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PracticeTime.ViewController 0x7feab750d130> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
*** First thr

Comment: Typecasting is handled automatically in `Swift4.0`

Comment: @FarasatNiazi, you have used tableView1 in your code. Update line `let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell",for: indexPath)`

Comment: yeah i have conected my table view from storyboerd in my viewcontroller file as " tableview1".

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal so what should i update in this line? i m confused

Comment: change `tableView` to `tableView1` in mentioned line. and check whether outlet of `tableView1` is connected on storyboard.

Comment: Just use `cell.textLabel?.text = Array(element.keys)[indexPath.row] and cell.imageView?.image = Array(element.values)[indexPath.row]` lines ignore else part.

Comment: @TheTiger i have already used that part its creating an exception. and

Comment: @FarasatNiazi Exception is for `tableView` not for `tableView1`. And you asked question about how to show the dictionary keys and values in cell. Is there any issue with creating a `cell/tableView` too?

Comment: Then just disconnect outlet and reconnect it & use above code.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all `keys` of dictionary and use `indexPath.row` to fetch the `key` and then fetch `value` by this `key`.

```
let keys = Array(element.keys)
let key = keys[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = key
cell.imageView?.image = element[key]
```

**Suggestion:** In case you want to maintain the order you will have to use `Array` instead of `Dictionary` as `Array(element.keys)` will return all keys sorted in ascending order. So below is the example:

```
let element = [["name": "Sports", "image": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios")], ["name": "Grocery", "image": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios")], ["name": "Cosmetics", "image": #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ios")]]
let info = element[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = info["name"] ?? ""
cell.imageView?.image = info["image"] ?? defaultImage
```

Comment: actually i have imageView in cell and generates an error like  "UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content." So how can i resolve it

Comment: You need just one `cell`. Why `Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.` ?